# Creating a very shallow curved edged div with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div for a navbar with a single and very shallow/wide curve as shown in my psd design below [image: PSD mockup I am trying to copy]

Here's a code scribble of closest I have been able to get it so far in codepen...
    http://codepen.io/pottymus/pen/KJCcL

I have played around with the numbers for ages in the border-bottom-radius but I am getting near but not quite there. I cannot overlap the 2 shapes that make up the nav as they are translucent (or part transparent) and so the overlap shows. Does anybody know how to make the very edges of the curve more like my picture? i.e. have less of a definite edge/end to the curve and instead appear to blend better into the rectangle div above?

Comment: It's difficult because you can't cheat with your nav and to change margin-top in negative. If you had a menu with opacity:1, it would be feasible

Comment: Yeah, maybe I just need to make one really huge transparent curved shape and offset off the canvas. I am trying to get advice to see if this is even possible to be honest.

Comment: What about an adding an inline svg path `<svg><path d="your custom path"/></svg>` and then position the nav element on top of it. If you import your psd into illustrator you should be able to grab your curve path without too much trouble.

Comment: That's a very interesting idea Kerry I will investigate. I have never used SVG paths before and sadly don't own Illustrator as I am just a photoshop/css user, but I am going to read up on how it all works anyway as it looks like it has endless potential.

Comment: @user2317093 Check out the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathElement It's pretty straight forward but a pain to write out by hand. Maybe try [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)? You should at least be able to trace over your image.

Comment: SVG is the correct answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define S alike curves (like [Besier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) that you need there) with border radius, so this is closest you can get with them:

```
.curve {
    height: 30px;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 30px ;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 30px ;    
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank man I am beginning to come around to the idea that you might be right, looks like I have a decision to make.